# How do I fill up automatically a drop down list from a SQL query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm trying to populate a drop down box list from a SQL query dinamically. How do I make it create automatically more  tags depending on the query result.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `nombre`, `apellido` from `members` WHERE `operador` = 'digitel'",$link) or die ("Hubo un problema en la consulta del reporte" . mysql_error());
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);

}
?>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='process.php' method='post'>
<table border=1 bordercolor='#000000'><tr><tr>
<table width='50%' border=0>
<tr><td bgcolor='#C0C0C0'> FECHA<font color='#ff0000'>*</font></td>
<td bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
<select name='FECHA' size="1">
<option value="<?php echo $data2[nombre, apellido]?>"></option>
</select></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT nombre,apellido FROM members WHERE operador = 'digitel'",$link) or die ("Hubo un problema en la consulta del reporte" . mysql_error());
?>
<form action='process.php' method='post'>
  <select name='FECHA'>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['nobre'].'">'.$row['appelido'].'</option>';
}
?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on the echo line

Comment: Your syntax problem is somewhere before or somewhere after this code snippet! This small code above has perfectly correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use mysql_query, use mysqli instead, mysql is depreciated. Use the code below to replace the option tag line.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `nombre`, `apellido` from `members` WHERE `operador` = 'digitel'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo    '<option value="' . $row[nombre] . $row[apellido] . '">' . $row[nombre] . $row[apellido] . '</option>';
    }

}
```

Comment: I get this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING. The code is like this:
`    <select name="NOMBREDELASESOR"><?php 
    $result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `nombre`, `apellido` from `members` WHERE `operador` = 'digitel'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
          echo    '<option value="' . $row['nombre'] . $row['apellido'] . '">' . $row['nombre'] . $row['apellido'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `nombre`, `apellido` from `members` WHERE `operador` = 'digitel'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo    '<option value="' . $row[nombre] . $row[apellido] . '">' . $row[nombre] . $row[apellido] . '</option>';
}
```